# Why can't I use a loop-cut on this simple mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I just tried making a person in blender from a tutorial (first time I use blender) and somehow I can't make a loop-cut in the last 'box' thing. [image: Yellow is what blender does, red is what I want added]
It is nor a triangle nor an N-gon, I checked for double sides/vertices but nothing seems to work.

How can I get a loop cut here?

The yellow is what blender does, and the red is what I want added

Here's the blend model: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=50184

Comment: Look into non-manifold geometry, in this case this might be inner face visible on your screenshot (just where your red line touches edge loop, 1 face above loopcut made by Blender). Possibility to add a loopcut isn't related to mesh complexity, rather to its geometry

Comment: The failure of Ctrl-R  to offer you a loop cut can be very useful for 'debugging' meshes which look OK, but have invisible faults, like internal faces. I sometimes use it with no intention of actually making a cut.

Comment: That's actually very useful! I'll probably use that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems that make Blender unable to know how it could build the edge loop, as it needs quads to create edge loops automatically with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>, and it can't deal with ambiguity:

- A face inside your mesh that is not visible in Object mode. You need to select it and delete it with <kbd>X</kbd> > Faces
- An edge loop coming from the bottom which makes a ngon at its end. You need to select it and delete it with <kbd>X</kbd> > Edge Loops

Now you can create a new edge loop.

[image]